# How to get coordinates of specific measurement in line layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinates, mapping

Let's say I draw a line through a map in QGIS and I know the coordinates of the Start-point and endpoint, but I need to know how could I get the coordinates of a specific distance (inside) line... Example my drawing line is let say 5km, and I want to detect coordinates in 2km.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your coordinate system in in meters (otherwise adapt accordingly), you can use the *Geometry by expression* tool with the `line_interpolate_point` function.

###### Tool settings

[image]

Your line layer as input, and the following expression:

```
line_interpolate_point($geometry, 2000)
```

###### Result

- For each line in your line layer, this will return a point 2000 meters along it.
- For lines shorter than your specified distance, no point will be returned.

[image]

###### Getting the coordinates of the point

To get the coordinates from the returned point, a second expression can be used in the field calculator on the layer generated above:

```
-- get X,Y coordinates of point as string (using || to concatenate the values separated by a comma)
x($geometry) || ', ' || y($geometry)
```

[image]

*Of course, X and Y can be calculated into separate fields if needed*

Comment: Good point, will add, thanks! Given how quickly the answer was upvoted, I guessed someone else was busy with it :)

Answer (score 3):

The answer provided my Matt above is prefectly correct. Make sure you have a geometric coordinate system, which we assume is geometric so that you can calculate in meters. Once you have that at a project level, then you should be set.

The second part that you need to keep in mind is that you should always be aware of what is your starting point in the line layer. Let me explain: you state that your line is 5km long. Once you interpolate at 2km, as you wish to know that point, then you end up with two points along that line. The first one shold be the location you want to find the coordinates. However, if the point from where you want to know the X and Y is the end vertex of the line in GIS, then you may easily end up in the “wrong 2km point”. The shape of the line is irrelevant, but the questions is, is theline in GIS starting left-to-right, and is the left side your starting point. If yes, then you have your desired X and Y coordinates.

Assuming that these lines form some sort of network, pipeline, road, powerline network, then you may be looking at a more advanced solution within your (GIS) system, where you are also storing M dimension (linear reference system/dynamic line segmentation). Also, the real world is not flat, so depending on your needs, you may also need a way to account for Z dimension (height)?

To build a linear reference system in your network layer,there is one extension for QGIS that I am aware of (may be others too), called LSR that you may want to have a look at: [Linear reference system builder and editor](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/lrs/).

I hope this helps!